# SELECT multiple variable columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a restaurant reservation module using PHP.

The problem is that I would like to make the user choose which time they would like to come and which time the would like to go.

Between these two times the table needs to be occupied, so there needs to be a name in that cell between those times.

I have no idea how to get this done.

Here is my existing code:

```
$day="0".$_POST['day'];
$month="0".$_POST['month'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$date=$year ."-". $month ."-". $day;
$table=$_POST['table'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$fromtime=$_POST['fromtime'];
$untiltime=$_POST['untiltime'];
$tablenumber = $table;

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="root";
$database="restaurant";
$connection = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $password)
    or die ("could not connect with server");
$db = mysql_select_db ($database, $connection)
    or die ("could not connect with db");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE table='$tablenumber' AND date = '$date'");
?>
```

Comment: What's the structure of your `tables` table? By the way, if possible, stop using `mysql_` http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: Also, you have made no call to update the value in the table - only selecting it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a one to many relationship with a table for the reservations (if they can only reserve 1 table), so you need an insert statement to add a reservation

Here some **pseudo code**

```
INSERT INTO reservation (tableid, startTime,endtime,reservationName) VALUES (tableid, yourFronttime, yourEndTime, reservationName)
```

but before inserting you have to check if the table is free like this

```
SELECT tableId
FROM reservation 
WHERE (startTime BETWEEN yourFrontTime AND untilTime) OR (endtime BETWEEN yourFrontTime AND untilTime) 
AND TableId = yourId
```

If you got results with that select they got to choose another time or another table.

Comment: Why on Earth must you `SELECT *` to see if records exist? A simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` would suffice.

Comment: it's only an example... I don't think they will copy/paste this speudoCode... You don't even need a Count(*).. you could select any column and it's only for guidance, I didn't even concat or use a prepared statement for the parameters. But I will edit my answer just in case. Thank you.